# OSCommerce Product Listing Shows Inaccurate Count and Results Per Page

Tags: math, resultset, oscommerce

http://www.roguevalleyroses.com/rose_list.php?search_id=&class=&height=&growth=&color=&bloom_size=&bloom_type=&shade=&fragrance=&disease=&rebloom=&thorns=&zone=&hybridizer=Ashdown%20Roses&date_range=&text=&view=&show=&page=4

This is the page. The code that queries the results is here: http://pastebin.com/d51bfa53f

I can't make any sense out of how OSCommerce works. Let me know if you need anything else. Also, is this just a common problem in SQL Queries, PHP loops, or in some math being wrong? I am looking to be pointed in the right direction, not necessarily needing an exact answer as this is a hacked/custom OsCommerce.

Comment: unfortunately it is not,

Comment: There is some dodgy maths going on because of some bad SQL in the code. Plus the Pastebin is no longer valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think this is spam..

this is a common issue with oscommerce.. esp custom contributions add in for more trouble when it comes to queries.. oscommerce navigation class does not support for use of distinct or group by clauses.. i.e, to say when it counts for the records, it does not consider those keywords.. you would need to modify the split page results class to fix this.

Cheers
Shiva

Comment: that's the best suggestion to date, thank you so much. we're going to probably move to ubercart with drupal.

Comment: I avoid modifying the OSC core code, so rather than editing the splitPageResults class either see Gerv answer below (github link is useful), or think of extending the splitPageResults class to suit your needs.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the "group by" clause which the osCommerce code cannot deal with - in the splitResults class file.  Struggled with this for a while, and this was my first attempt at fixing it:

```
if (strpos($sql_query, 'group by')) {
    $reviews_count_query = tep_db_query("select count(*) as total from (select count(*)" . substr($sql_query, $pos_from) .") as GroupedResult");
} else {
    $reviews_count_query = tep_db_query("select count(*) as total " . substr($sql_query, $pos_from, ($pos_to - $pos_from)));
}
//$reviews_count_query = tep_db_query("select count(*) as total " . substr($sql_query, $pos_from, ($pos_to - $pos_from)));
```

However, with further testing, that is not working properly either.  I then spent some time working out what was going on exactly, and found similar code already existed in oscommerce at https://github.com/osCommerce/oscommerce2/blob/bda6f6df3e4ab027b72ecfe6a96ac70b6774b312/catalog/admin/stats_customers.php#L40-L45

Here you can see the splitpageresults class is "group by" clause...and then underneath is the "fix" to place the corrected amount of customers into the numrows query.  And that query is then appropriated by the splitpageresults to make the "showing x of y results".

Comment: Not sure if this answer has been expanded on, since Cyril's Comment, but it was a useful answer for me.